# OnTime function Confusion

Tags: vba, excel

I have written down below VBA code to be executed after every 5 seconds but it does not work.

```
Option Explicit

Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 5 ' two minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "TheSub"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub


Sub TheSub()
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Your code here
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    MsgBox "hi this is working"
    StartTimer  ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub
```

What is that I am missing here ?

Also a simple expression like below also don't works

```
Sub test()
    Application.ontime (now() + TimeValue("0:0:5")),"test"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do not schedule the OnTime if you are going to rerun StartTimer upon completion of the called procedure.

Comment: @Jeeped I need to schedule the OnTime to keep these functions call in loop.

Comment: `RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)`  Not "TimeValue"

Comment: @TimWilliams AFAIK both functions returns the time, TimeValue takes a string while TimeSerial takes long, Also I have tested this thing using TimeSerial as well but it still does not work.

Comment: Works fine for me with that change.  Your code as posted causes a compile-time error on `TimeValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the [TimeSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z.aspx) function, not [TimeValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz2ahtzs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
Option Explicit

Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 5 ' two minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "TheSub"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat
End Sub


Sub TheSub()
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Your code here
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Debug.Print "hi this is working"
    StartTimer  ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub
```

This works and you can watch the VBE's Immediate window to see it run through.

Comment: Oh,Okay my bad I just mixed both of these function and confused myself